# Inconsistent behavior involving VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures.fillModeNonSolid

Tags: vulkan

I departed slightly from the Vulkan tutorial I was following and decided to draw a wireframe instead of a solid triangle.

As soon as I call `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines()`, I get the following message from Validation Layer even though the call finishes with `VK_SUCCESS`.

> `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines` parameter, `VkPolygonMode` `pCreateInfos-> pRasterizationState->polygonMode` cannot be `VK_POLYGON_MODE_POINT` or `VK_POLYGON_MODE_LINE` if `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures->fillModeNonSolid` is false.

For good measure I check the `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures` right after I call `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines()` and `fillModeNonSolid` is `VK_TRUE`.

The output is a wireframe triangle as expected but the message got me worried if I am missing something.

I am using Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050Ti (driver 417.22), Vulkan 1.1.82.1 on Windows 10(64-bit).

PS: I am experiencing similar problem with wideLines feature as well:`VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures` has `wideLines` as `VK_TRUE` but Validation Layer thinks it is set to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the fillModeNonSolid feature needed to be explicitly enabled during logical device creation.